# a "loader" next to a button using a style

Tags: android, android-layout, loading

I'm still new to *Java* in general, so I decided some **SOF** input would be helpful on this question-

I have a `Button` that, when *clicked*, I want a `ProgressBar` to show next to it. I would like to do this with a style, preferably to just send the needed style via `setBackgroundDrawable`.

I've done this in **CSS** a number of times where I just add a `class` which contains the background element I need and pushes the text out a handful of pixels. I'm hoping I can do something similar because I have a lot of `Button` objects to perform this on.

I've used JS to create an example of what I want to accomplish. I'm hoping this will iterate my point better:
http://jsfiddle.net/puPdK/3/

Please feel to let me know if there is a better way. I'm all ears! **Thanks.**

Comment: do you want that sipnning thing as a background of a button. if so see this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Comment: Very interesting.. I'd much rather use the `ProgressBar` if there is a way to do that. If not, I'll have to do something like what you linked. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the best way to do this (to my knowledge) was to wrap my button in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. When the button is clicked, I add a `new ProgressBar` as child zero to my the layout (eg `container.addView(myProgressBar, 0)`. When the loading is done, I then remove the first child from my layout `container.removeViewAt(0)`. Viola.

Answer (score 0):

Animated GIF does not work with android.

so if you want to animate something in your case frameanimation can be used.

or you can use ProgressBar.setIndeterminate which will show a spinning circle. and you can use view's visibility.

we don't have the javascript part of HTML/CSS/JavaScript, which is missing in android's xml/stye/? as you have asked.

we have to see the java code more of the server-side or back-end code.